# JPA issue (lazy loading? eager ?)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Iam building a simple Spring Boot app, with 2 entities:

```
- Student model

    @Entity
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Student {
     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private String password;
     private boolean active;
     private Date dob;
     private String roles;
     @ManyToOne
     private Training training;
    }

- Training model

    @Entity
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Training {
      @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
      private Long id;
      private String name;
      private int duration;
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "training")
      @JsonIgnore
      private Collection<Student> students;
    }
```

EDIT

I run the app by adding 2 resources in the db:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MsSchoolingSbApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        
        Training t1=trainingRepo.save(new Training(null,"php", 20, null));
        Training t2=trainingRepo.save(new Training(null,"java", 20, null));
        Student st=new Student(null, "XXXX", "ZZZZ", true,new Date(),"ADMIN",t1);
        Student st2=new Student(null, "XXXXX2", "ZZZZZ2", true,new Date(),"USER",t2);
        studentRepo.save(st);
        studentRepo.save(st2);
    }
```

END EDIT

EDIT 2

```
- StudentRepo
@RepositoryRestController
public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>{

    public List<Student> findByNameStartsWith(String name);
    
    Optional<Student> findByName(String name);
}

- TrainingRepo
  @RepositoryRestController
    public interface TrainingRepo extends JpaRepository<Training, Long> {
    
    }
```

END EDIT 2

i've tried to put **fetch = FetchType.EAGER**  or **LAZY**, i've also added **@JsonIgnore** but as soon as i fill the db with new data (trainings and students) and run the app, i get this message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.schooling.models.Training.students, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use Lombok's @Data annotation on @Entity classes.

Reason: @Data generates hashcode(), equals() and toString() methods that use the generated getters. Using the getter means of course fetching new data even if the property was marked with FetchType=LAZY.

Somewhere along the way hibernate tries to log the data with toString() and it crashes

EDIT
you can exclude the relation from the toString method by adding, for example in my case:
@ToString(exclude = {"students"})

Answer (score 0):

- The problem you got must have related to how you use those 2 entities so you need to provide more information about how you use it.
- You might want to look out for your problem in this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-initialize-proxy-exception

Comment: unfortunately i tried already what is in this article but it doesn't work: adding property in application.properties (spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true) and FetchType.EAGER on students list in Training entity
If i add them both i get "java.lang.StackOverflowError: null"

Comment: So how do you use those entity? Did you mean you just run the program without use those 2 entity and got exception?

Comment: check the text i've edited it with the data i add in the db.

Comment: @YoussefHarkati I'm guessing trainingRepo and studentRepo are using JpaRepository interface, but I know that Hirbernate Session was already managed by Spring so your problem shouldn't be happen. Can you also provide the code of trainingRepo and studentRepo

Comment: Yes i've edited it with the 2 repos (EDIT 2). Thank you

Comment: Try add @JoinColumn(name = "student_id") in the Training entity, under @ManyToOne.

Comment: when we use mappedBy with OneToMany we can't use JoinColum, because it's already mapped and it throws an exception

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like JoinTable or JoinColumn: com.schooling.models.Training.students

Comment: I actually found the cause of the cylce....lombok....as soon as i take off Data annotation and put getters setters, it works.

Comment: @YoussefHarkati wow i never thought of that. If that is the case then you could use "@EqualAndHashCode.exclude" and "@ToString.exclude" so you can still use "@Data".

Comment: I'll try that definitely and let you know if that helps. That would be great because lombok is really useful

Comment: i used @ToString(exclude = {"students"})  and it worked